# How to declare startActivityforResult() in one line in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to call `startActivityforResult` in a one line statement in Kotlin. Something like this:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity2,MainActivity::class.java),1))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Option 1: Use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents) library:**

```
startActivityForResult<MainActivity>(1)
```

**Option 2: You can create your own extension Function on Activity or AppCompactActivity:**

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> Activity.myStartActivityForResult(requestCode: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, T::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}

myStartActivityForResult<MainActivity>(1)
```

Comment: Please edit the answer with the setResult code in MainActivity.

Answer (score 4):

This is a clean way to do a one line call for startActivityForResult. In the result activity you will have to create a companion object to set up the launch intent.

**Activity**

```
class MyActivity {
    companion object {
        const val CONTACT_REQUEST = 1
    }

    fun activityCall() {
        startActivityForResult(MyActivity.getLaunchIntent(this), CONTACT_REQUEST)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == MyActivity.CARD_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The user picked a contact.
                // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

                // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result Class**

```
class MyResultActivity {
    companion object {
        fun getLaunchIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
            return intent
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Java:

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = result.getData();
            // Handle the Intent
        }
    }
});

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    // ...

    Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // The launcher with the Intent you want to start
            mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, ResultProducingActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

In Kotlin:

val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        // Handle the Intent
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    // ...

    val startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button)

    startButton.setOnClickListener {
        // Use the Kotlin extension in activity-ktx
        // passing it the Intent you want to start
        startForResult.launch(Intent(this, ResultProducingActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```